# Tex Live for Mac (MacTex) has font problems (reinstalled every time)

Tags: fonts, mactex

I have significant font problems with my MacLive Distibution: some packages I am using in a document seem to have special font demands, so there is nothing I can do about it.

What is happening: 
- I am using pdflatex and at the end of the run it generates fonts that seem to be missing.
   However, next run same thing. 
For several hours no chance to solve the problem. I tried to use all the information I could find, but either the solution did not work or it was not clear what to do from the description. 
 So I removed my complete basic ! MacTex/TexLive distribution and reinstalled the Full version. As a result some of the fonts are now unproblematic, but new fonts make problems. 
below is the final dump from this new installation. 
I tried with the example of cm-super again for an extended period to solve the problem. 
To no available.
- I tried to register it as a Map (it is already listed as MixedMap in the updmap.cfg file) manually, 
- I ran updmap-sys
- I reinstalled the font from the platform (although it was there)
- .. and several other things that were proposed..

none made any difference so far.

Thanks in advance for your help 
  Klaus

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report} 
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{texnames} 
\begin{document} 
\textbf{\BibTeX-entry} 
\end{document}
```

PS: the new installation was with the newest MacTex distribution 2012 and the whole thing happens on a MacBook 2010, running Mountain Lion.

(see the transcript file for additional information){/usr/local/texlive/2012/te
xmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-t1.enc}

Comment: what do you mean with MWE?

Comment: Please see [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/22413)

Comment: ok, got it. The acronym was the problem..

Comment: Not sure, whether this is the real correct MWE, but it shows some some of the issues.. 
\documentclass{report}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{texnames}

 
\begin{document}
\textbf{\BibTeX-entry}
\end{document}

Depending on whether the fontenc is commented out or not a different font trailer is shown.

However, let me rephrase the problem: 
Is this trailer with the font lists actually a problem (because in pdf I do no longer see the lack of type1 fonts

Comment: And here the output.. - much fewer fonts, the rest was removed

This is texnames.sty, Version 1.10 <02 March 1998>
) (./cover_min.aux) [1{/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updma
p/pdftex.map}] (./cover_min.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/fonts/typ
e1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/fonts/type
1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmcsc10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/fonts/type
1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on cover_min.pdf (1 page, 26436 bytes).

Comment: I'm very unclear about what's not working for you.  This example seems to compile fine.

Comment: Warm [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) and see [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for any details on MWE.

Comment: Ok, it looks like it is reproducing the fonts like /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/fonts/type 1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb 
right? Because I usually do not see a chain of fonts, if I am working with latex.

Comment: Have you tried to run `updmap` instead of `updmap-sys`?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an issue localised to a single machine.